# How To Write New RSS Item Line To The Top

Tags: php, rss, fopen, fwrite, fseek

I pieced some code together, it probably could be written better -- but it works and I have learned not to be picky with functional code. At any rate what I have here is some code that will automatically update a sitemap.xml file and "THE PROBLEM -- reason why I am posted the question here" an RSS feed file.

Writing to the sitemap.xml file works perfectly! I am pleased. It was easy because it writes new data at the bottom of the file and the closes out by writing `</urlset>`.

However, with the rss feed file, I need new items to go on the top. I can't seem to figure how to do that. So, attached here is the CURRENT copy of my code. Basically the second section titled RSS FEED WRITER is a duplicate of the first section titled SITEMAP.XML WRITER. Some how I need to change the code to the second section in order to write new items to the top directly below this line: `<atom:link href="http://mydomainname.com/index.rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />` on the index.rss file.

Thank you so much in advanced to anyone who is willing to help me. Here's the code below:

```
//
// SITEMAP.XML WRITER
//
$sitemapurl = "<url>";
$sitemaploc = "<loc>";
$sitemaplocation = "http://mydomainname.com/$url.php";
$sitemaploc1 = "</loc>";
$sitemappri = "<priority>";
$sitemappriority = "1.0";
$sitemappri1 = "</priority>";
$sitemapcha = "<changefreq>";
$sitemapchange = "daily";
$sitemapcha1 = "</changefreq>";
$sitemapurl1 = "</url>";

$sitemapurlset = "\n</urlset>";
$sitemaplength_end_string = strlen($sitemapurlset);

$sitemapfp =
fopen("sitemap.xml","r+") or die("can't open file");
fseek($sitemapfp, -$sitemaplength_end_string, SEEK_END); 
fwrite ($sitemapfp, "\n".$sitemapurl."\n".$sitemaploc."".$sitemaplocation."".$sitemaploc1."\n".$sitemappri."".$sitemappriority."".$sitemappri1."\n".$sitemapcha."".$sitemapchange."".$sitemapcha1."\n".$sitemapurl1."".$sitemapurlset."\n"); //added url set to here
      fclose($sitemapfp); 

//
// RSS FEED WRITER
//

$rssitem = "<item>";
$rsstitle = "<title>$title</title>";
$rsslink = "<link>http://mydomainname.com/$url.php</link>";
$rssguid = "<guid isPermalink=\"true\">http://mydomainname.com/$url.php</guid>";
$rsspubdate = "<pubDate>".date('D, d M Y H:i:s O')."</pubDate>";
$rssdescription = "<description>$metadescription</description>";
$rssitem1 = "</item>";
$rsschannelrssset = "\n</channel>\n</rss>";
$rsslength_end_string = strlen($rsschannelrssset);
$rssfp =
fopen("index.rss","r+") or die("can't open file");
fseek($rssfp, -$rsslength_end_string, SEEK_END);
fwrite ($rssfp, "".$rssitem."\n".$rsstitle."\n".$rsslink."\n".$rssguid."\n".$rsspubdate."\n".$rssdescription."\n".$rssitem1."\n".$rsschannelrssset."\n");
fclose($rssfp);
```

EDIT: Adding the top portion of the index.rss file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:lj='http://www.livejournal.org/rss/lj/1.0/' xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<title>My Domain Name RSS Feed</title>
<description>Description of My Domain Name RSS Feed</description>
<link>http://mydomainname.com/</link>
<atom:link href="http://mydomainname.com/index.rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

I then tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
//
// RSS FEED WRITER
//

$rssitem = "<item>";
$rsstitle = "<title>$title</title>";
$rsslink = "<link>http://mydomainname.com/$url.php</link>";
$rssguid = "<guid isPermalink=\"true\">http://mydomainnanme.com/$url.php</guid>";
$rsspubdate = "<pubDate>".date('D, d M Y H:i:s O')."</pubDate>";
$rssdescription = "<description>$metadescription</description>";
$rssitem1 = "</item>";
$rssatomlink = "<atom:link href=\"http://mydomainname.com/index.rss\" rel=\"self\" type=\"application/rss+xml\" />";
$rsslength_end_string = strlen($rssatomlink);
$rssfp =
fopen("index.rss","r+") or die("can't open file");
fseek($rssfp, -$rsslength_end_string, SEEK_END);
fwrite ($rssfp, "".$rssitem."\n".$rsstitle."\n".$rsslink."\n".$rssguid."\n".$rsspubdate."\n".$rssdescription."\n".$rssitem1."\n");
fclose($rssfp);
```

Comment: why are you not using an [XML extension](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) for this?

Comment: I didn't know about it. I will research it as I have time, but for now I would like to just finish this code up so that it can be functional. Once that is up and running, I can also improve the site after it is live.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PHP Universal Feed Generator](http://ajaxray.com/blog/php-universal-feed-generator-supports-rss-10-rss-20-and-atom). It supports RSS 1.0 / 2.0 and ATOM 1.0.

Comment: I'll take a look when I can. In the mean time, all I really need is to figure out a way make a command to write directly below this line: `
<atom:link href="http://mydomainname.com/index.rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />` in the index.rss file. If I can figure that out, then that's all I need for now.

Comment: I strongly propose to stop your own effort. Using a framework allows to focus on RSS - not PHP-code. Using a framework, thus quite likely simplifies or eliminated your current problem.

Comment: Additionally, better use an array to manage your data, not a large set of variables. PHP's arrays have huge set of operations - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php - well suited to manipulate their contents.

Comment: I really appreciate your insight with this. These are undoubtably excellent points. All that remains for me to have this code as being functional is figuring out a way to simply write directly below this line: `<atom:link href="mydomainname.com/index.rss"; rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />` on the index.rss file. From there, I have no objection towards learning how to do things a better and improved way. But for the time being, this will work fine. Any assitance specifically with modifying the code in order to write directly below that line will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: At this point I'm out. The above code has too few structure to apply a nice fix. Nevertheless: Why not create a function/method, which encapsulates some work.